# Using Codelite on Mac with wxWidgets but Language Server cannot wx includes

Tags: macos, wxwidgets, codelite

I have installed Codelite 15.0.6 and also wxWidgets-3.1.5 from source using procedure on this site. https://docs.codelite.org/build/build_wx_widgets/ When creating project using wxCrafter - wxDialog or any wx[Method] the project can not clean or build.

```
/usr/bin/make -j16 -e -f  Makefile clean
----------Cleaning project:[ C-Simple-Projects - Debug ]----------
make[1]: wx-config: Command not found
make[1]: wx-config: Command not found
rm -f -r ../build-Debug/C-Simple-Projects
=== build completed successfully (0 errors, 0 warnings) ===
```

I can understand the Compiler & Linker Options setting which calls wx-config --cxxflags is unable to be found, but calling `wx-config --cxxflags` from the command line works.

```
sudo make install
```

which completed successfully and can find wx-config in my shell using terminal.

```
    > % wx-config --cxxflags
-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.1 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DwxDEBUG_LEVEL=0 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXMAC__ -D__WXOSX__ -D__WXOSX_COCOA__
```

My problem is also that the Language Server shows file not found.

Comment: can you show the output of `ls -la /usr/local/lib`?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x    1 root          staff   1872704 Sep 11 01:17 libwx_baseu-3.1.5.0.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root          staff        27 Sep 11 01:17 libwx_baseu-3.1.5.dylib -> libwx_baseu-3.1.5.0.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root          staff        23 Sep 11 01:17 libwx_baseu-3.1.dylib -> libwx_baseu-3.1.5.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root          staff    334384 Sep 11 01:17 libwx_baseu_net-3.1.5.0.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root          staff        31 Sep 11 01:17 libwx_baseu_net-3.1.5.dylib -> libwx_baseu_net-3.1.5.0.0.dylib
... many more

Comment: also noticed wx-config fails on both clean & build from the IDE when the configuration calls wx-config relatively. If I add the fully qualified path to the Compiler options and Linker, then code is compiled. e.g. -g;-O0;-Wall;$(shell wx-config --cxxflags --unicode=yes  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed settings for make in the project to "default" and the application started building.  Issue is related to Codelite makefile generator setting. I also changed the compiler options to include fully qualified path to wx-config executable. Will try to use Save as Template - see if that will generate other projects with these setting preconfigured.  Fingers crossed.  actually adding `-std=cxx17` to linker options did the trick.  resolved!